# Smooth color with GL_QUAD_STRIPS

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw this color map in OpenGL

[COLOR_MAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlMfX.png)

When using QUADS, the result look fine:

```
int colorArr[] = { 255, 224, 192, 160, 128, 96, 64, 32 };
gluOrtho2D(-2, 2, -2, 2);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    glColor3ub(colorArr[7 - i], 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-4, i - 4);
    glVertex2f(4, i - 4);
    glVertex2f(4, i - 4 + 1);
    glVertex2f(-4, i - 4 + 1);
}
glEnd();

glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glLogicOp(GL_OR);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    glColor3ub(0, colorArr[i], 0);
    glVertex2f(i - 4, 4);
    glVertex2f(i - 4, -4);
    glVertex2f(i - 4 + 1, -4);
    glVertex2f(i - 4 + 1, 4);
}
glEnd();

glFlush();
```

But if I use QUAD_STRIPS to draw the polygons, the color get smooth between the lines:

```
int colorArr[] = { 255, 224, 192, 160, 128, 96, 64, 32 };
gluOrtho2D(-2, 2, -2, 2);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    glColor3ub(colorArr[7 - i], 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-4, i - 4);
    glVertex2f(4, i - 4);
}
glVertex2f(-4, 4);
glVertex2f(4, 4);
glEnd();

glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glLogicOp(GL_OR);

glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    glColor3ub(0, colorArr[i], 0);
    glVertex2f(i - 4, 4);
    glVertex2f(i - 4, -4);
}
glVertex2f(4, 4);
glVertex2f(4, -4);
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

Do you have any idea why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quad strip you're drawing is equivant to this:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    glColor3ub(colorArr[7 - i], 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(-4, i - 4);
    glVertex2f(4, i - 4);
    glColor3ub(colorArr[7 - i+1], 0, 0);
    glVertex2f(4, i - 4 + 1);
    glVertex2f(-4, i - 4 + 1);
}
```

You are changing color every 2 vertices and the color is interpolated as an attribute to the next/previous points.